# Representing a set of URLs in a list as a tree structure

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts that stores URLs. It has simply two fields, `title` and `url`. Example:

```
[
  {'title': 'Index Page', 'url': 'http://www.example.com/something/index.htm'}, 
  {'title': 'Other Page', 'url': 'http://www.example.com/something/other.htm'},
  {'title': 'About Page', 'url': 'http://www.example.com/thatthing/about.htm'},
  {'title': 'Detail Page', 'url': 'http://www.example.com/something/thisthing/detail.htm'},
]
```

However, I'd to get a tree structure from this list of dicts. I'm looking for something like this:

```
{ 'www.example.com': 
  [ 
    { 'something': 
      [ 
        { 'thisthing':
          [
            { 'title': 'Detail Page', 'url': 'detail.htm'}
          ]
        },
        [
          { 'title': 'Index Page', 'url': 'index.htm'},
          { 'title': 'Other Page', 'url': 'other.htm'}
        ]
      ]
    },
    { 'thatthing': 
      [ 
        { 'title': 'About Page', 'url': 'about.htm'}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My first attempt at this would be a urlparse soup in a bunch of for loops and I'm confident that there's a better and faster way to do this.

I've seen people on SO work magic with list comprehensions, lambda functions, etc. I'm still in the process of figuring it out.

(For Django developers: I'll be using this my Django application. I'm storing the URLs in a model called `Page` which has two fields `name` and `title`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Third time is the charm... that is some nice structure you have there :). In your comment you mention that you *"haven't been able to think of a better tree format to represent data like this"*... this made me again take the liberty to (just slightly) alter the formatting of the output. In order to dynamically add subelements, a dictionary has to be created to house them. But for "leaf nodes", this dictionary is never filled in. If desired these can of course be removed by another loop, but it cannot happen during the iteration because the empty `dict` should be present for possible new nodes. The some goes for nodes that do not have a file in the: these will contain an empty `list`.

```
ll = [
  {'title': 'Index Page', 'url': 'http://www.example.com/something/index.htm'}, 
  {'title': 'Other Page', 'url': 'http://www.example.com/something/other.htm'},
  {'title': 'About Page', 'url': 'http://www.example.com/thatthing/about.htm'},
  {'title': 'Detail Page', 'url': 'http://www.example.com/something/thisthing/detail.htm'},
]

# First build a list of all url segments: final item is the title/url dict
paths = []
for item in ll:
    split = item['url'].split('/')
    paths.append(split[2:-1])
    paths[-1].append({'title': item['title'], 'url': split[-1]})

# Loop over these paths, building the format as we go along
root = {}
for path in paths:
    branch = root.setdefault(path[0], [{}, []])
    for step in path[1:-1]:
        branch = branch[0].setdefault(step, [{}, []])
    branch[1].append(path[-1])

# As for the cleanup: because of the alternating lists and
# dicts it is a bit more complex, but the following works:
def walker(coll):
    if isinstance(coll, list):
        for item in coll:
            yield item
    if isinstance(coll, dict):
        for item in coll.itervalues():
            yield item

def deleter(coll):
    for data in walker(coll):
        if data == [] or data == {}:
            coll.remove(data)
        deleter(data)

deleter(root)

import pprint
pprint.pprint(root)
```

Output:

```
{'www.example.com':
    [
        {'something':
            [
                {'thisthing':
                    [
                        [
                            {'title': 'Detail Page', 'url': 'detail.htm'}
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                [
                    {'title': 'Index Page', 'url': 'index.htm'},
                    {'title': 'Other Page', 'url': 'other.htm'}
                ]
            ],
         'thatthing':
            [
                [
                    {'title': 'About Page', 'url': 'about.htm'}
                ]
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: This only seems to work for paths one-level deep. I shoudl have been more explicit. It doesn't work for URLs like this `http://www.example.com/thisthing/thisthing/about.htm`.

Comment: Hi Jro. I'm not at liberty to change the models so that's out. The reason for doing the above is to return all these records over JSON. You're right about the fact that checking whether a a node is a list to see it if is a set of pages is ugly but I haven't been able to think of a better tree format to represent data like this. I'm back to original issue of trying to convert that list of URLs into the example data format. I really appreciate your help but if somehow you could show me how to get convert it, it would a relief. I've been beating my head over but but no luck. Thanks Jro.

Comment: Aha. Thank You. Thaks you Jro. I've already accepted your answer but one small thing: how could i remove all the empty dicts and lists? Would I need to recurse to traverse the whole tree?

Comment: I added a cleanup proposal to the answer.

Comment: Thank you Jro. I managed to piece together something as well. have a look at my answer below. It requires cleanup but it's a very different approach. I'll be using this function on a list of 5000+ items so I'm wondering what would execute faster.

Comment: Not much of a difference :). I quickly timed the two implementations, and they are almost identical in execution speed: with 500000 elements (in the `pages` list), the difference is that mine is on average 0.05 seconds faster with an average execution time of 4.437 seconds (4.493 for yours). Your intended usage of 5000 elements is by both scripts completed in ~0.03 seconds. (This machine is a Core2 Duo E8400@3GHz)

Comment: Okay. I'll go with your method. I've further cleaned up my code to be neater and use `filter` functions. If you're interested.

Comment: Thanks for this. It helped me get over a hump in grouping masses of redirects into location blocks. My [code](https://github.com/CNG/redirects-generator/blob/95fd0bbf66ee711b3b277262e765949e6091dcae/generate.py#L83) could use some work… new to Python, but learning the above helped immensely.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. It seems to work. A very different approach from Jro's:

```
import itertools
import pprint

pages = [
  {'title': 'Index Page', 'url': 'http://www.example.com/something/index.htm'},
  {'title': 'Other Page', 'url': 'http://www.example.com/something/other.htm'},
  {'title': 'About Page', 'url': 'http://www.example.com/thatthing/about.htm'},
  {'title': 'dtgtet Page', 'url': 'http://www.example.com/thatthing/'},
  {'title': 'Detail Page', 'url': 'http://www.example.com/something/thisthing/detail.htm'},
  {'title': 'Detail Page', 'url': 'http://www.example.com/something/thisthing/thisthing/detail.htm'},
]



def group_urls(url_set, depth=0):
    """
    Fetches the actions for a particular domain
    """
    url_set = sorted(url_set, key=lambda x: x['url'][depth])

    tree = []

    leaves = filter(lambda x: len(x['url']) - 1 == depth, url_set)
    for cluster, group in itertools.groupby(leaves, lambda x: x['url'][depth]):
        branch = list(group)
        tree.append({cluster: branch})

    twigs = filter(lambda x: len(x['url']) - 1 > depth, url_set)
    for cluster, group in itertools.groupby(twigs, lambda x: x['url'][depth]):
        branch = group_urls(list(group), depth+1)
        tree.append({cluster: branch})

    return tree

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for page in pages:
        page['url'] = page['url'].strip('http://').split('/')

    pprint.pprint(group_urls(pages))
```

I can't seem to figure out why I need to sort at the beginning of every recursion. I bet if i worked that around, I could shave a off another couple of a seconds.