# Covert an array of route data to an tree data structure which can be used in Vue router

Tags: javascript

I have folllowing route structure from the backend server and I want to transfer it to a tree structure which can be used as an Vue route config.

I am stuck at how can I split the path for each child, while there is no other property related to path

```js
const flattenSideMenuData = [
  {
    path: '/1',
    title: 'title1',
    icon: <AppstoreOutlined />,
  },
  {
    path: '/1/1-1',
    title: 'title1-1',
    icon: <MassageBoxOutOutlined />,
  },
  {
    path: '/1/1-2',
    title: 'title1-2',
    icon: <MailOutlined />,
  },
  {
    path: '/1/1-3',
    title: 'title1-3',
    icon: <MailOutlined />,
  },
  {
    path: '/1/1-3/1-3-1',
    title: 'title1-3-1',
    icon: <MailOutlined />,
  },
]
```

After convert, it will be like:

```js
  {
    path: '/1',
    title: 'title1',
    icon: <AppstoreOutlined />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/1-1',
        title: 'title1-1',
        icon: <MassageBoxOutOutlined />,
      },
      {
        path: '/1-2',
        title: 'title1-2',
        icon: <MailOutlined />,
      },
      {
        path: '/1-3',
        title: 'title1-3',
        icon: <MailOutlined />,
        children: [
          {
            path: '/1-3-1',
            title: 'title1-3-1',
            icon: <MailOutlined />,
          },
          {
            path: '/1-3-2',
            title: 'title1-3-2',
            icon: <AppstoreOutlined />,
          },
          {
            path: '/1-3-3',
            title: 'title1-3-3',
            icon: <MassageBoxOutOutlined />,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
```

Comment: I think we're all struggling ot understsand what your end game is here. If you're referring to dynamic routes, check out https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html. An example route would be "{ path: '/user/:id', component: User }" where ":id" is an identifier (string or integer, in this example). If you can provide a better explanation, we might be able to further help you achieve your goal or point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Here the input is an array of route data while each route path is the whole path from root to the current node. What I want is to change them to a tree structure.

Comment: I don't follow the whole "tree structure" concept.

Comment: the tree structure will be like the second code snippet above

Comment: Sorry, I still do not follow what you're after. I would love to help, I just don't understand. The router is designed to handle static and dynamic routes, as defined in the router config. It can be simple and it can be complex. If you're referring to something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794489/representing-a-set-of-urls-in-a-list-as-a-tree-structure I am not sure what that will achieve but you would just break apart the URL on the page that you land on.

Comment: The each level of the output tree is generated by the route path in the array data structure

Comment: It is just like an algorithm problem and nothing related to the route actually

Answer (score 0):

I am still unsure what you're really after but these routes will handle what your example snippets show but in a dynamic fashion. You want to avoid using duplicate code and instead, use components which is what frameworks like VueJS and React are designed for besides being reactive.

```
{
  path: '/:id',
  component: () => import('@/app/component')
  children: [
    {
      path: '/:id-:id',
      component: () => import('@/app/component2')
      children: [
        {
          path: '/:id-:id-:id',
          component: () => import('@/app/component3')
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The route `/1` would hit the first `path` and would be shown the `@/app/component` where the route `/1-1` would be shown the `@/app/component2` so on, and so forth.

Comment: Ok, I think you are working on the design of Vue. You can think my question is like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181311/tree-structure-from-array-paths-using-javascript

Comment: Ah, yeah, good luck with that. I have not seen that done in Vue yet. Your original question was directly related to Vue (vuerouter) so I am not entirely sure how the answer would not be in direct correlation with vuerouter.

Comment: I would recommend using the code from the SO document that you posted as well as with this code to build your routes dynamically using a JSON object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56317020/vue-router-build-from-json